# How to retrieve a file/image in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize and i have successfully uploaded a file to a folder and saved it's name in the database.Now i want to retrieve the image in postman.I am getting the name of the image when i use the get request.How to do I get the actual Image which has been stored in the uploads folder.

Below is my code.

middleware/upload.js

```
 const multer = require("multer");

const imageFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype.startsWith("image")) {
  cb(null, true);
   } else {
    cb("Please upload only images.", false);
  }
   };

  var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
  cb(null, "./uploads/");
 },
   filename: (req, file, cb) => {
   let name =  `${Date.now()}-Shehryar-${file.originalname}`
   req.body.fingerPrints = name
   cb(null,name);
  },
  });

   var uploadFile = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: imageFilter });
   module.exports = uploadFile;
```

route/user.js

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const user = require('../controllers/user.controller.js');
const upload = require("../middleware/upload");
const user_router = Router();

user_router.post('/createUsers',upload.single("fingerPrints"),user.create);
user_router.get('/getall', user.findAll);
user_router.get('/get/:code', user.findById);
user_router.put('/update/:code', user.update);
user_router.delete('/delete/:code', user.delete);

module.exports = user_router;
```

controller/user.js

```
 exports.create = (req, res) => {
    let codeGenerate = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,7);

End_user.create({
    code:codeGenerate,
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    middleName: req.body.middleName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    nickName: req.body.nickName,
    email: req.body.email,
    mobileNumber: req.body.mobileNumber,
    bloodGroup:req.body.bloodGroup,
    fatherName: req.body.fatherName,
    motherName: req.body.motherName,
    bForm: req.body.bForm,
    fingerPrint: req.body.fingerPrints
}).then(user => {
    res.send({message :`User Created With Code ${user.code}`});
}).catch(err => {
  res.send(err.message);
 });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Is Simple You Have to Put below code in your app.js or srever.js

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));

// Above line would serve all files/folders inside of the 'uploads' directory
// And make them accessible through http://localhost:yourport/uploads.
```

So now when we upload image (lets say sample.png) it will be stored uploads folder and will be accessible on web page on the url `http://localhost:3000/uploads/sample.png`

Comment: i am using postman i dont have any front end yet. Let me share the finAll function with you.

Comment: End_user.findAll().then(users => {
   res.send(users);
 }).catch(err => {
     res.send(err.message);
  })

Comment: How to get all other attributes plus the image which is stored.? Using the postman..

Comment: you have to setup this retrive url in frontend

Comment: if you are uploading users image you can convert them in to base64 or you can store the image url like i have given in answer and in frontend you have to put this url link in image tag source

Comment: put this in your craete user function      fingerPrint: `http://localhost:3000/uploads/${req.body.fingerPrints}`

Comment: As i told you before I dont have frontend i am working with APIS through postman. I have multiple users and each user has his fingerprint saved in a folder.How do i retrieve the fingerPrint image for each user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234410/discussion-between-arya-and-shehryar-tanoli).

Comment: Kindly Check your chat